Do Carmo and Locally Symmetric Spaces
In Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, Chapter 4, locally symmetric spaces are defined to be ones where the curvature tensor is parallel ($\nabla R = 0$), and the following problem is given:
If M is locally symmetric, $\gamma: [0,l) \rightarrow M$ a geodesic, and $X,Y,Z$ are parallel vector fields along $\gamma$, then $R(X,Y)Z$ is a parallel field along $\gamma$.
I solved this by a calculation equivalent to the answer appearing here. What I can't figure out at the moment is: Where do we use the assumption that the curve $\gamma$ is a geodesic?

I feel that $\gamma$ need not be geodesic. When it is smooth, the proof also is effective.  But I'm very weak,  what I say may be wrong.

@EnhaoLan I also suspect it's not necessary. What's driving me crazy is that no one has seemed to notice this...not even Jack Lee, who commented under the the linked post!

What if $\gamma$ is a closed curve? Then you are unlikely to get a well-defined continuous parallel transport ... unless $\gamma$ is a geodesic.

@TedShifrin Could you elaborate? The only thing I know about transport around closed curves is that it defines holonomy.

Precisely. So in the presence of holonomy you will not get a global parallel frame on $\gamma$ unless the closed curve is a geodesic.

@TedShifrin I see what you mean now. Seems like the problem could have been split into nonclosed and closed cases. As far as I can tell, Do Carmo does not even mention holonomy in this book.

Well, the level of what we’re discussing — with or without the term — shows up in undergraduate geometry texts.
